# exec() cause an infinite loop of starting requested program

Tags: php

OS: Linux.

WHM, cpanel used.

PHP 5.3.2 (cli) (built: Jun 11 2010 02:25:31)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies

```
<?php
exec("php xyz.php");
?>
```

starts calling the xyz.php innumerable times. the server hangs after sometime.

calling 'php xyz.php' from the console works fine.

Comment: Why are you using PHP to run a system command to run PHP?

Comment: I don't get it, can you elaborate? Is the above code in the file `xyz.php`, or is it calling itself otherwise?

Comment: @BoltClock i need to do some admin scripting which are written in php...
@deceze the above code is in a different php file. say index.php.

Comment: And what is in the `xyz.php` ?

Comment: anything...i have put in just a echo to test...even that is being called over and over...had to killall the php processes to save the server...an exec("whoami") works fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

found the solution from

http://www.mombu.com/php/php-5-forum/t-24759-exec-or-system-et-all-cause-an-infinite-loop-of-starting-requested-program-8469354.html

```
<?php
exec("php-cli xyz.php");
?>
```

worked....