# php exec infinite loop

Tags: php, loops, exec

I have the following which call the exec to run the script test.php in the background.

```
exec("/home/gooffers/test.php?one=one &");
```

Script test.php contains the following

```
$test = $_GET['one'];
echo $test;
```

However this is creating an infinite loop (infinite number of processes) which is crashing the server. Why is this happening.

Comment: We need to see more of how `exec()` is being used in your code, to see if there's an infinite loop in your main code.

Comment: @davis, This is all the code that i have as you see it in my question.

Comment: Hudhud - Thank you for replying - But just the same, could you please update your post with the complete contents of both your main script (which contains the exec() ) and the test.php script... By complete I mean "<?php" and all - full copy/paste of the entire file.  In addition could you please show how you are executing your main script ? Thank you

Comment: @david, you don't understand. This is all the code in both files. One file contains just the exec and the other file contains just the 2 lines GET and echo. That's all the code that i have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$_GET` is not availible when you are running a script via commandline (php-cli).

See here on how to pass arguments to a command line script in php: [How do I pass parameters into a PHP script through a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612166/passing-command-line-arguments-to-a-php-script)

Basically, it's

```
exec("/home/gooffers/test.php arg1 arg2");
```

and then fetching them via

```
$argument1 = $argv[1];
$argument2 = $argv[2];
```

Comment: `$argv[0]` refers to the script file (/home/gooffers/test.php), so `$argv[1]` equals the first argument. But you're right, this is the good way. Working with php processes, I'm used to use something like: `list($command,$args) = array(array_shift($argv), $argv)`.

Comment: Reading thru pages online i thought it's possible to have it the way i posted. Although i haven't verified it yet since exec for some reason keeps going into a loop and crashing the server. Your post seems to be the correct way to do it. I will try it and see how it works. I still don't understand why exec is going into a loop. I found many posts online talking about exec and infinite loops. One person suggested that we use php-cli instead on php. Don't know if that would make a difference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615713/exec-cause-an-infinite-loop-of-starting-requested-program

Comment: I would suggest trying it the correct way with command line arguments. Maybe this solves your infinite loop problem right away.

Comment: Very strange, must have to do something with your server / php configuration. never experienced any problems with exec. But give it a shot!

Comment: @hedhud Try what http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#101506 suggests for running a background process.

Answer (score -3):

I dont know what is happening, but i think it should be

```
exec("php /home/gooffers/test.php?one=one &");
```

Comment: No. Your command will work if you use wget, something like `exec("wget http://localhost/gooffers/test.php?one=one &")`, but not if you're using php cli. PHP cli uses C-like nommage to take arguments, so `$argc` and `$argv`.