# Usage of system function in production code

Tags: php, python, c

Why is it told that, usage of system function in a production code is not advisable?
How is this different from using exec family of functions?

Clarification: I have read it in many places that, it is unwise to use system function, when we are doing something at a commercial level. But It never occurred to me as what might be the problem, and how using exec family is considered better than system .As far as I am concerned, my concerns are clarified

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732832/php-exec-vs-system-vs-passthru

Comment: If the input is coming from external sources or users, definitely you should avoid it or sanitize it. For example, you read a line of data and then do `os.system`, user can input `echo "Welcome" > test.txt`. This would create a file on your server. This is just an example, the actual attack vectors would be very interesting and dangerous.

Comment: In Python you should use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module(with `shell=False` for [untrusted input](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments)) not the functions provided by the `os` module.

Comment: Re the 'put on hold' state, I thought it was reasonably clear. He's asking why `system` is unadvisable whereas `exec` is not.

Comment: @abligh, that's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is tagged C, php and python. I don't know python, but C and PHP functions `system` functions differ in at least one respect: the PHP function has an optional second argument.

In C (and according to the documentation, PHP does the same thing), `system` runs the command by executing `/bin/sh -c command`. The issue here is whether `command` is completely under your control. If `command` is a constant string, you are reasonably safe. However, if `command` has any user provided elements, you better be very careful. Let's say you thought this was a good way to add a string `$foo` to a log.

```
system ("echo '$foo' >> /var/log/bar");
```

in php is not going to be a great idea, because `$foo` might contain the following (including the quotes)

```
'x && /bin/rm -rf / && echo '
```

Much better use something like `exec` where you don't need to worry about quoting, separating parameters etc. (rather than pass it through `/bin/sh`), and even then you need to be very careful.