# Programatically set log level in syslog

Tags: php, logging, syslog, rsyslog, syslog-ng

How do I programatically set log level in syslog-ng?

So for I have set the log level by editing /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf 
and restarting the syslog-ng service.

```
service syslog-ng restart.
```

I have a php app and I want users to be able to set the log level from the web UI.

How to I programatically set the log level for syslog-ng using either php/linux?

I've seen something about setlogmask($mask_priority) but I can't see how I can use this using php/linux.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

PHP have some functions to invoke shell commands/scripts. Check these 2 links:

[PHP shell_exec function](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.shell-exec.php)

[Stackoverflow - PHP - exec() vs system() vs passthru()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732832/php-exec-vs-system-vs-passthru)

If you need to do sudo with no password you'll have to insert the apache user into the sudoers file and specify/modify the use of no password for that user. Though this seems to me a huge security hole, if somebody achieves to log as apache user then he'll become root.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/168461/how-do-i-sudo-without-having-to-enter-my-password

Comment: What I"m looking for is the actual command to set the priority of syslog-ng globally in either php or linux.