# Get HTTP connections without php exec

Tags: php, http, exec

Is there any option to get all domain related HTTP connections that are made without `exec`?

I am using `netstat | grep http | wc -l` in terminal, and in php I am using exec.

The question is if there is any option to get this without the "exec" function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can find any native PHP functions for replacing 'netstat'. 'netstat' is one of the tools provided by 'net-tools' package (http://sourceforge.net/projects/net-tools/). You have to use 'exec' or 'system', no other go.  ([PHP - exec() vs system() vs passthru()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732832/php-exec-vs-system-vs-passthru))

THere seems to be some netstat php scripts, which i didn't checked out fully, you can try them out if you like. However i don't think they can provide you with 'all domain' information.

https://github.com/netstat-php/netstat_php/blob/master/netstat.php

http://www.fam.tuwien.ac.at/~schamane/_/netstat_php