# PHP - What exactly is exec() calling?

Tags: php, exec

I'm sorry to ask what seems to me is a dumb question but after reading [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and doing some experiments I'm not sure what exactly exec() is calling when I run, for example,

```
exec("getType \"$file\"",$out);
```

Is it the same as me typing the command in a command prompt or will it run the function getType which can be defined elsewhere in the program? If it is the prior where does getType come from? If it is the later why would I not just call the function in a script like usual?

Thanks for any help clearing this up, it is very much appreciated.

Comment: [exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) — `Execute an external program` should be your clue: the keyword is __external__

Comment: It uses a shell to execute the command, so it's much the same as if you typed `getType` into your shell.

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732832/php-exec-vs-system-vs-passthru