# How can I export MySQL database with a PHP script?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-backup

I need one script that when I open the `script.php` page for example, that export me one database from MySQL to an SQL document, and I don't know how to do it in PHP, can some one help me with that?

Edited Code:

```
<?php

$dbhost   = "localhost";
$dbuser   = "root";
$dbpwd    = "";
$dbname   = "activmanagement";
$dumpfile = $dbname . "_" . date("Y-m-d_H-i-s") . ".sql";

passthru("D:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/bin/mysqldump --opt --host=$dbhost --user=$dbuser --password=$dbpwd $dbname > $dumpfile");

// report - disable with // if not needed
// must look like "-- Dump completed on ..." 

echo "$dumpfile "; passthru("tail -1 $dumpfile");

?>
```

This line:

```
passthru("D:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/bin/mysqldump --opt --host=$dbhost --user=$dbuser --password=$dbpwd $dbname > $dumpfile");
```

Comment: just use `mysqldump` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: then you would do it the slow inefficient way @PHPglue

Comment: @Dagon so i edited my question and i used that code and it worked, but im runing in wamp like u see if my website was on a host the part on "This line" it would be different right?

Comment: the path to mysqldump would be different, everything else is the same

Comment: @Dagon so how can i see the right path if i host my website? :s

Comment: how would i know how your host has set its servers up? how about asking them?

Comment: but if the website is hosted the path its the same or almost the same in any host right?

Comment: their path (if its needed) to `mysqldump` could be *anything*

Comment: hoo, but if it does not need a path so what would be the code?

Comment: then simply `mysqldump --opt --host=` ,,,

Comment: @Dagon you know how to save it in zip file?

Comment: pipe it `mysqldump -u usuario -p --all-databases | gzip > dump.sql.gz`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP regular backup of mysql data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916163/php-regular-backup-of-mysql-data)

Answer (score 0):

Refer [PHP - exec() vs system() vs passthru()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732832/php-exec-vs-system-vs-passthru). You just need something like this

---

```
<?php
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';
    $dbname   = 'activmanagement';

    $sql_backup_file = $dbname . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . '.gz';
    $dump = "mysqldump --opt -h $dbhost -u $dbuser -p $dbpass $dbname | gzip > $sql_backup_file";

    system($dump);
?>
```