# Imagemagick Composite Overwriting File

Tags: php, imagemagick, composite

Good day. I am new to Imagemagick, and I just wanna ask what's wrong with this code

```
$cmd_for_wm = "composite -gravity southeast watermark.png image.jpg image.jpg;";    
exec($cmd_for_wm);
```

When I run it in the terminal, it is working well, but when I incorporated it in PHP, it doesn't work. Why?

Thanks for you in advance :) Cheers

Comment: It might be a path issue. Try using absolute paths (just for testing)

Comment: actually used the absolute path, but doesn't work @AlexTartan

Comment: Any error messages? Anything in the error logs?

Comment: there's actually no errors in the log :/ @AlexTartan

Comment: Try passing the output argument to `exec` like: `$out = array(); exec($cmd, $out); print_r($out);` and post the output

Comment: returns an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your example and it does "die" silently.
This, on the other hand seems to work:

```
$cmd_for_wm = "composite -gravity southeast watermark.png image.jpg image.jpg;";    
passthru($cmd_for_wm);
```

Very curious indeed. Since the main difference between `exec` and `passthru` is the output handling. The later is used for binary data.

My take on this is that `passthru` correctly allows `composite` to output the processed image (which *is* binary data) into the specified file.

For a detailed explanation, please see [PHP - exec() vs system() vs passthru()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732832/php-exec-vs-system-vs-passthru)