# PHP system() function - does it use shell to execute command?

Tags: php

I read a related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/732832/682869) and I get the impression that the `system()` function in php does not use a shell. But then saw the following example posted on [owasp](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Command_Injection) - example 6 on the page:

The following PHP code snippet is vulnerable to a command injection attack:

```
<?php
print("Please specify the name of the file to delete");
print("<p>");
$file=$_GET['filename'];
system("rm $file");
?>
```

The following request and response is an example of a successful attack:
Request

```
http://127.0.0.1/delete.php?filename=bob.txt;id
```

Response

```
Please specify the name of the file to delete

uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data)
```

Without a shell, why would system fall for the semicolon OR does system() function implementation in php identifies the semicolon in that way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does use the shell. I didn't see any answer in the question you linked to that said it doesn't.

The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) says:

> `system()` is just like the C version of the function in that it executes the given command and outputs the result.

Since the C function uses the shell, so does the PHP function.

The documentation is slightly misleading, because the C function doesn't return any of the output of the command, while the PHP function returns the last line of the output.

Comment: I was confused because php has a function called `shell-exec()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) .. I thought why would they need two of them ?

Comment: I don't know why PHP has all those different functions for executing commands. But as far as I can tell, they all use the shell.

Comment: They differ slightly in how they return the output. `shell_exec` returns all the output as a string, `system` returns just the last line, `exec` returns the last line and appends all the output lines to an array passed by value.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, and this example will show you :

```
echo system("echo $0");
```