# Starting node function from PHP button

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

Someone Could tell me how start node function from PHP.
For example I want to load some data from node http request and load it to PHP website.
Please put any tutorials or part of code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use php's `exec` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php - just so long as you are not using any user input in your command. I don't know of a tutorial for this.

Here is a SO on the different ways to make calls to your system: [PHP - exec() vs system() vs passthru()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732832/php-exec-vs-system-vs-passthru)

Comment: My application is enabled, and has na few functions.
I want to call for example to `app.loadData()` and get json data.
I do not want turn on the application because it is already enabled but only execute one function from them and display it on website.

Comment: there is no way of that I know that you can call a node method from inside php (basically, execute node code in PHP is what it sounds like you're trying to do). You'll have to make a node executable file that runs your method, then take the output and do something with it in PHP. That's all I know - maybe someone knows another way.

Answer (score 0):

Your node.js code should run a simple http server listening on the loopback interface, so your php code can request the data using a http request.

Another option is to run the node server on a public url (on a different port or using a reverse proxy) and let it return data using JSONP.