# pngquant PHP example isn't working

Tags: php, pngquant

I am trying to use the [pngquant](https://pngquant.org/) compression algorithm to compress PNG images on the fly using WAMP. They provide a [PHP example](https://pngquant.org/php.html) that (I think) is supposed to use the [command line binary for Windows](https://pngquant.org/pngquant-windows.zip), which I have put in the `system32` folder and I can access from anywhere on the command line.

I have taken their example and traced the problem to the `$compressed_png_content = shell_exec("pngquant --quality=$min_quality-$max_quality - < ".escapeshellarg(    $path_to_png_file));` line. I have simplified it to `var_dump(shell_exec('pngquant - < test.png'));` but it only outputs the first 5 characters even though `passthru('pngquant - < test.png');` seems to send the correct output to the user as a string. `exec('pngquant - < test.png',$output); var_dump($output);` also seems to capture the correct output but in a form of an array, which I don't really know how to convert back into an image file. I want to capture the output in a variable so I can use further compression algorithms and manipulations and send it to the user as a downloadable file.

I have read up on the [diferences between system() vs exec() vs shell_exec() vs passthru() vs proc_open() vs popen()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21016100/2051323). Shell_exec() seems to be the correct choice, however it says on php.net that [shell_exec()'s](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) outputs a string. Could that be a problem? How do I correctly capture the `pngquant - < test.png` command output to a variable?

Comment: Just saying, PNG images are already highly compressed. But still, a reseached question +1.

Comment: I'm a web designer. Most of my PNGs and other designer's PNGs I work with can be compressed by 40% to 70% with no visually observable deterioration using this algorithm. I think it's pretty worth it :)

Comment: Did you come up with a solution?

Comment: @sanjihan no, not yet sanjihan.

Comment: Too bad. What operating system are you using?

Comment: @sanjihan Windows, like I say in the post.

Answer (score 2):

Use a PHP wrapper ([php-pngquant](https://github.com/ourcodeworld/php-pngquant)) for PNGQuant instead, I've come across with the same issue, and this non-official wrapper has finally saved me.

```
function compress_image($source_path, $destination_path, $quality){
     $instance = new PNGQuant();

    // Change the path to the binary of pngquant, for example in windows would be (with an example path):
    $instance->setBinaryPath("E:\\wamp64\\www\\testing\\pngquant\\pngquant.exe")
        // Other options of PNGQuant here
        ->execute();

    // Set the path to the image to compress
    $result = $instance->setImage($source_path)
        // Overwrite output file if exists, otherwise pngquant will generate output ...
        ->overwriteExistingFile()
        // As the quality in pngquant isn't fixed (it uses a range)
        // set the minimum quality to 60
        ->setQuality(60, $quality)
        // Retrieve RAW data from pngquant
        ->getRawOutput();

    $exit_code = $result["statusCode"];


    // if exit code is equal to 0 then everything went right !
    if($exit_code == 0){

        $rawImage = imagecreatefromstring($result["imageData"]);

        // Example Save the PNG Image from the raw data into a file or do whatever you want.
        imagepng($rawImage , $destination_path);

        echo "Image succesfully compressed, do something with the raw Data";
    }else{
        echo "Something went wrong (status code $exit_code)  with description: ". $instance->getErrorTable()[(string) $exit_code];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks dexterb. I'll take a look into how, exactly, this wrapper handles the raw output :)