# How to recognize palm lines from a palm image using php

Tags: php, imagemagick, canny-operator

From the orientation of palm, I need to detect the palm is left or right, and also I want to extract the lines from the palm, is there any PHP library available ? or how can I use canny in php

[image: Palm lines are shown here]

Answer (score 0):

I doubt very much that there's a native library in PHP for this sort of thing. It's not exactly the language of choice for complex image recognition.

You can call external programs in PHP with `exec()`, `system()`, `passthru()`, `popen()` and `proc_open()`. [Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732832/php-exec-vs-system-vs-passthru) about how they work and what the differences are. You can then use Canny or other software of choice with their usual command line usage.