# PHP 433 MHz Raspberry Pi

Tags: php, raspberry-pi

I wrote a PHP file to control my wireless socket with 433 MHz. I want to run it in my local network by typing in the browser: "ip of server"/socketOn.php 
It is not going to turn on the socket.
This is my PHP code:

```
machine("sudo /home/pi/raspberry-remote/./send 11000 4 1");
```

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, PHP doesn't have a `machine()` function. You will want to look at these instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732832/php-exec-vs-system-vs-passthru

Answer (score 0):

As Markus AO already mentioned in his comment, there is no `machine()` function in PHP. You should use [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), [system()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php), [shell_exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) or similar PHP functions to execute a shell command.

The code could then look like this, assuming that `/home/pi/raspberry-remote/send` is executable:

```
<?php
exec("/home/pi/raspberry-remote/send 11000 4 1");
?>
```

Note that some [restrictions may apply to these functions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.functions.php), if PHP runs in [safe mode](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php). According to the official PHP documentation, for `exec()`, `system()` and `passthru()` these restrictions are:

> You can only execute executables within the [safe_mode_exec_dir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode-exec-dir). For practical reasons it's currently not allowed to have .. components in the path to the executable. [escapeshellcmd()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php) is executed on the argument of this function.