# How to run cmd commands in php (exec/system)

Tags: php

I am trying to run cmd command exec and system via php code, but it is showing me nothing. Is there anything I need to enable in php.ini???

Comment: Which function do you use to try to run cmd ? Did you try `exec()` ?

Comment: Take a look at [PHP - exec() vs system() vs passthru()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732832/php-exec-vs-system-vs-passthru)

Comment: yes i am using exec()

Comment: still not working for me :(

Answer (score 3):

**1 -** it depend on what you write inside `exec()`
and This command only executed on the server side , 
and cannot be executed on the client side

**to use this command :** 
- for example u can write : `<?php echo exec("ping google.com"); ?>` to know the ping of google and the result will appear in your browser page 
 - use `shell_exec("ping google.com");` to show more detail
 
- Another Example to use that command : `shell_exec('systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name"');` 
to show what operation system u use. 
Another solution is to create a bat file , name it : "***Simple.bat***" and save it on the root of your website 
then simply use this command to call it : `<?php echo exec("Simple.bat"); ?>`

**2 -** if you ruining IIS the issues could be something inside your settings and the causes are many when u come to this part , and i dont have Experience at IIS , * only Apache 
but one of the solutions suggest about IIS can be founded here in first reply : 
https://forums.iis.net/t/1216283.aspx

Comment: <?php echo exec("ping google.com"); ?>  also not working. Error:-   exec(): Unable to fork [ping google.com]

Comment: sorry, can you pls tell me how to check if server have previlege to run an external application? bcoz not a single cmd command running from my website. I am using IIS.

Comment: @pk27 what u runing your pc on : windows or linux ? - and what PHP version u have

Comment: windows and PHP 5.2.0

Comment: @pk27 write this command `echo system("ulimit -a");` then tell me what message show to you .

Comment: warning:- system(): Unable to fork [ulimit -a]

Comment: Actually I need to access a shared folder which has username and pwd. for that I need to use system("net use ", ....); command. But it is just not running :(

Comment: @pk27 look for this file on your system : " **php.ini** " open it and press Ctrl + F , then search for " **memory_limit** " and increase the size of that option make it 100m or more , depend on what u need // for me 200m is enough ;

Comment: It was 128M, I changed to 200M, but still showing the same warnings, can't run exec/system, net use etc

Comment: @pk27 it could be from your local server IIS software . uninstall it and change it with apache :: **Download and install Apache 2.2 or higher** ,  then put your code page in `www` directory inside apache folder and run your page `localhost/yourpage.php` from any Browser and it should run fine .
Last Versions for Pc : http://directory.apache.org/studio/download/download-windows.html

Comment: It worked after doing this: https://forums.iis.net/t/1216283.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your time

Comment: @pk27 so the issues was on IIS software as i expect in the last comment , good to know that u fix it .