# Unable to execute /usr/local/bin/program using PHP exec()

Tags: php, macos

I'm using OSX and MAMP. In my mac terminal, running the following commands gives the following output
`whoami` gives... `pengkong`
`ffprobe -version` gives... `ffprobe version 3.3.2 Copyright (c) 2007-2017 the FFmpeg developers...`
`which ffprobe` gives... `/usr/local/bin/ffprobe`

Using PHP
`echo exec('whoami');` also gives... `pengkong`
`echo exec('ffprobe -version');` gives empty back
`echo exec('/usr/local/bin/ffprobe -version');` gives `libpostproc 54. 5.100 / 54. 5.100`

Why am i unable to run `ffprobe` without specifying the absolute path `/usr/local/bin/ffprobe` using PHP with the exec() function?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - exec() vs system() vs passthru()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732832/php-exec-vs-system-vs-passthru)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exec` searches for any specified program in the directories listed in [include path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-include-path.php). If you only get the expected output for a program via absolute path, it may mean that its parent directory isn't set in the include path so you should [set it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) if you want to execute that program w/o path.

If directory in question *is* set in the include path and you still get the unexpected behaviour, use the second and [third optional parameters of exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to find out about the status of the process.