# Is PHP exec the only way to communicate to an outside program?

Tags: php, security, command-line-arguments

If I'm writing an application to communicate with a program, would using **`exec`** be the way to go, or is there another way?

Comment: There are other ways. `exec` might work fine though. Is something not working for you currently? Are you worried about some injection?

Comment: What are the other ways, I am going to communicate with a command line application, and I want a method that has little to no overhead

Comment: For example using exec I expect will open a cmd.exe program all the time to execute these commands (The same with linux)

Comment: How do most programmers go about communicating with a command line application? Or any piece of software really

Comment: Maybe this thread would be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732832/php-exec-vs-system-vs-passthru

Comment: You might want to check that exec is enabled on the server, on some servers it might be disabled

Comment: What do you mean "outside program"? Another process on the same server? A process on a different server? API? You need to elaborate on what you're trying to do

Comment: MySQL is an "outside program" is it not?