# Why is shell_exec not working even with full visudo permissions?

Tags: php, permissions

I realise that it is bad security practice to give `www-data` full permissions with visudo. However, even with the highest permissions, privileged shell commands do not work.

PHP Code in `/var/www/html/index.php`:

```
<?php
     echo shell_exec("ls"); //expected output is echoed 
     echo shell_exec("bitcoin-cli getbalance"); //does not output anything
?>
```

If I type either command into the shell myself, I get the output I expect.

My sudoers file looks like this:

```
...
root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d

www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Why is `shell_exec("any command I like")` not working with this configuration?

Comment: @vivek_23 that's a typo - apologies

Comment: @kerbholz question updated to be more relevant

Comment: Make sure it's not a `safe_mode` issue.

Comment: I can confirm it is not in safe_mode

Comment: It's difficult to track the issue without control over your system. Have you tried [the alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21016100/4964822)?

Comment: Thanks for the link - it appears none of the alternatives work