# Send value from php script to python script

Tags: python, php

I want to send string from php script to python:

**php script:**

```
$row = "successful";
        
$c= escapeshellcmd('python C:\wamp64\www\project\GUI.py ' .$row);
echo $c;
```

**python:**

```
url1 = 'http://localhost:9090/project/file.php'
    x2 = urllib.request.urlopen(url1)
    data = x2.read()
    d = str(data)

    encode = x2.info().get_content_charset('utf8')
    print(d)
```

i am getting nothing in python script kindly help thank you

Comment: python: some of the code provided is not enough.
What does len (sys.argv) give in Python?

Comment: PHP: Did you cehck what [escapeshellcmd()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php) actually does? It's for escaping data. It doesn't actually execute the command. There are plenty of examples in the manual. You can also read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732832/php-exec-vs-system-vs-passthru) with some info what function to use in what case.

Comment: @kubarik  when i use sys.argv[1] in python script it gives me out of index error

Comment: @kubarik 'What does `len (sys.argv)` give in Python?' it is giving 1 as output